# Como se muestra el texto en ruso sin errores de UTF-8 PHP

Tags: php, html

tengo un pequeño problema con una funcion que no me da corretamente el texto en ruso como puedo hacer que funcione sin este error.?

> Bien: Lectura en ruso "Американка путешествует" A2
>
> Mal: Lectura en ruso "ÐÐ¼ÐµÑÐ¸ÐºÐ°Ð½ÐºÐ° Ð¿ÑÑÐµÑÐµÑÑÐ²ÑÐµÑ"
>   A2

```
$meta = PHP_Get_Tags_(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xrDvaxEB-2s);
echo $meta['title'];




function PHP_Get_Tags_($url) {

    @$html = file_get_contents($url);

    @libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom = new DomDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $query = '//*/meta[starts-with(@property, \'og:\')]';
    $result = $xpath->query($query);

    foreach ($result as $meta) {
        $property = utf8_encode($meta->getAttribute('property'));
        $content = utf8_encode($meta->getAttribute('content'));

        // replace og
        $property = str_replace('og:', '', $property);
        $list[$property] =  utf8_decode($content);
    }

    return @$list;
}
```

Comment: tal vez tengas que enviar headers definiendo utf-8 como el charset `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` en el httpd.conf o `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` en el php antes de enviar/imprimir el texto

Comment: @aloMalbarez no me funciona eso

Comment: @aloMalbarez no tienes una otra funcion?

Comment: puede que el utf_decode esté de mas, o que el file_get_contents esté rompiendo la codificación fijate si esto te sirve: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#85008